# Dynamic derive Generic Type Parameter

Tags: c#, generics, recursion

I am using a recursive function for a object tree. That is, my object collection is like:

```
Object1
--Object2
----Object3
------Object4
```

All objects inherits from a base object (abstract class), where has a Validate() method, and its collection inherits from ITreeCollection. I have written a recursive function to perform that:

```
private bool Validate<T>(ITreeCollection items) where T : TreeNodeBase
        {
            foreach (var itm in items as Collection<T>)
            {
                if (((TreeNodeBase)itm).Items != null)
                {
                    return Validate<T>(((TreeNodeBase)itm).Items);
                }
                else return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

How can I derive the the type parameter T for the inner function (i.e. `return Validate<T>(((TreeNodeBase)itm).Items)`)

Comment: Side note: avoid `as` cast if cases where you do not immediately check for null as you convert a perfectly intelligible cast exception into a null ref exception and quite often at a code site unrelated to the cast.

Comment: Another side note: your loop returns after validating the first item in the list of items. I imagine you only want to return if `Validate` returns false so that the rest of the items get validated. As it stands you'll get the result for the very first leaf.

Comment: It does not look like you need any generics here at all: replace `T` with `TreeNodeBase`, and things would just work.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - You are right, thanks a lot for pointing out, +1 for you.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as it stands, you are not using the type parameter `T` so it could safely be removed. However I imagine you might want to do some type specific validation so this is perhaps not that helpful a suggestion. But, without example of what you want to do with `T` it's difficult to make suggestions.

Anyhow, here's one approach of what I *think* you are trying to do:

```
private bool Validate(ITreeCollection items)
{
    foreach (TreeNodeBase node in (IEnumerable) items)
    {
        // validate the node itself first
        if (!Validate(node))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (node.Items != null)
        {
            // validate its children
            if (!Validate(node.Items)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private bool Validate(TreeNodeBase node)
{
    if (node is BananaNode)
    {
        var bananaNode = (BananaNode) node;
        //TODO do BananaNode specific validation
    }
    else if (node is AppleNode)
    {
        var appleNode = (AppleNode) node;
        //TODO do AppleNode specific validation
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot validate node of type '" + node.GetType().Name + "'.");
    }
}
```

You could get snazzy with the dynamic keyword and get rid of some of this type checking but it does get a bit confusing and I'd advise against it:

```
private bool Validate(ITreeCollection items)
{
    foreach (TreeNodeBase node in (IEnumerable) items)
    {
        // validate the node itself first
        if (!Validate((dynamic) node)) // this will call the most appropriate version of Validate
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (node.Items != null)
        {
            // validate its children
            if (!Validate(node.Items)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private bool Validate(BananaNode node)
{
    //TODO do BananaNode specific validation
}

private bool Validate(AppleNode node)
{
    //TODO do AppleNode specific validation
}

private bool Validate(TreeNodeBase node)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot validate node of type '" + node.GetType().Name + "'.");
}
```